# Making a scroll view in Xcode 6 storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm trying to make a very basic layout in a storyboard in Xcode 6 with content that is too big to fit on the screen. I'm trying to use a UIScrollView and place a view inside of it, then put what I want in there, but it isn't working properly. This used to be so simple before auto layout. Can anybody please tell me how a scroll view with content larger than the screen in done in iOS 8?

Comment: You have added 'Label' to teh scrollview for the content, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add Constraints of Scrollview like this.

[image]

and Innner view of Scrollview Must be like this.

[image]

Bottom Constraint of UIView must be attached to UIScrollView and its constant value must be 0.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem perfectly. It's such a simple concept but it's so hard to find things about it online. :)

Answer (score 0):

When working with scrollViews you need to be careful not to confuse the frame with the content. Make sure your constraints from the scrollview are to the parent view but the elements in the scrollView have to be in the contentView of the scrollView.